# zend memcache gives error

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

Please help me for the issue of getting a error, while trying to implement a memcache with my application to speed up as below:

"The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend"

I am using the zend version: 1.11.11. 
I have the php_memcache.dll in my c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

I have implemented with below script:

```
    $frontendOptions = array(
            'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
            'automatic_serialization' => true
    );

    $backendOptions = array(
        'servers' =>array(
            array(
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 11211
            )
        ),
        'compression' => false
  );

  // getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
  $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
        'Memcached',
        $frontendOptions,
        $backendOptions);

  Zend_Registry::set('mem_cached', $cache);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check with carefully some point as below

mainly PHP has two Memcached libraries with confusing names :

[Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

[Memcached (notice the d)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)

Your code needs the first one. Just do a simple pecl uninstall memcached and then pecl install memcache, modify your php.ini to include the appropiate .so and it should work for you.